# How can I replace a CSS body background image with randomly shown images on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, page-refresh

Replace a css body background image style with code that randomly shows images on refreshing page?

This is the code that I want to replace

```
\<style\>  
body{background: url('\<?php echo $wo\['config'\]\['theme_url'\];?\>/img/welcome/background.png') !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}  
\</style\>
```

I am new at this, I have tried code downloaded from the internet that worked using very simple html, javascript and css in a folder, but I can't translate it to work with the above. I think it may not be relevant. That's why I decided to post here.

At the moment the above code shows a single image for the background of the body tag. I would like the body background image to change to another image randomly choosen from images in a specfied folder. What would be the best way form me to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please add code snippets around your HTML code and all your code globally. It's more readable for users that want to help you.

Supposing your images are in the folder you provided, the code should be like this :

```php
<?php $files = glob($wo['config']['theme_url'] . '/img/welcome' . '/*.*');$file = array_rand($files);echo $files[$file]; ?>
```

instead of

```php
<?php echo $wo['config']['theme_url']?>/img/welcome/background.png
```

This will take all the files in your config directory, and select an index randomly. Then you have just to pick the file name of the index `$file` and display it with `echo`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You stated that "This will take all the files in the config directory". Could you please clarify how I should implement this code. Thanks.

Comment: If this were working with a static file, then you succeeded to access the right directory. I have called it config because this is the partial name you gave in `$wo['config']['theme_url']`.
As I said, you just have to replace the second code snipped with the first one and say us what happen.

Comment: Thanks again. I replaced the exsiting with the new code and checked the web page. The entire page was blank.

Comment: The page had stop loading at \<style> body{background: url('\

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate a random number that changes the name of the file that acts as wallpaper

```
<style>
      body{background: url('\<?php echo $wo\['config'\]\['theme_url'\];?\>/img/welcome/background<?php echo rand(1,10)?>.png') !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}  
</style>
```

With this code it will try to access 10 different images called:
background1.png,background2.png ..etc

For this you must have those 10 images with those names in your images folder

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this option. However, as soon as I pasted it in place code from point of insertion greyed out. I saved and checked the the web page, but it was blank.

Answer (score 0):

to randomly background image you can write some JavaScript like this:

```
  <style>
    body {
      /* Remove the existing background styles */
      background: none !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const imageUrls = [
        '/path/to/image1.jpg',
        '/path/to/image2.jpg',
        '/path/to/image3.jpg',
        // Add more image URLs as needed
      ];
      
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length);
      const randomImageUrl = imageUrls[randomIndex];
      
      document.body.style.background = `url(${randomImageUrl})`;
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
      document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
      document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code and removing the background with css worked fine. However, I couldn't get the javascript to show the images. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong here. I even replaced the paths to the images with full paths. Could you offer further assistance with the javascript?

Comment: I have four files in the welcome folder using the naming format background1.png, background2.png etc.